# Unable to initialize DbContext with seed data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

1. You enter this function when launching the site in a browser
2. But it does not add data to the database

```cs
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Seed(AppDbContext context )
    {
        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            context.Users.AddRange(
                new User { Id = 1, Name = "jjjjjj", Password = "bbbb" },
                new User { Id = 2, Name = "zzzzz", Password = "ggggg" }
            );
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`AppDbContext` database Entity

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace task.Models
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<User>Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`User` model

```
namespace task.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`DbInitializer`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace task.Models
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Seed(AppDbContext context )
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any())
            {
                context.Users.AddRange(
                new User { Id = 1, Name = "jjjjjj", Password = "bbbb" },
                new User { Id = 2, Name = "zzzzz", Password = "ggggg" }

                );
               
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Main` function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using task.Models;

namespace task
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var host= CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Seed(context);
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            host.Run();

        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json` with connection string

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-HP5LSH2\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Dbtest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: You're swallowing any exceptions that might occur using that try-catch block. This is really bad practice, you should either log the exception or get rid of that try-catch.

Comment: How to call :                   
 ``` var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext();
     DbInitializer.Seed(context);

If you call without

Comment: How to call :                   
 ``` var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext();
     DbInitializer.Seed(context);
```
If you call without  try-catch.  
It gives the following error :-
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException HResult=0x80131500 Message=An error occurred while updating the entries
at task.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: That's the real error why the data is not inserted in the db. Putting empty try catch block will not solve the error but it will hide the error. Do you see any exception message when this error occurs?

Comment: Please post the error or specific message received (if any).

Comment: Could you please share your startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

You likely haven't registered the `DbContext` within `Startup`. Try adding the following in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` within `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>               
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

An example can be seen im the [Register the SchoolContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-the-schoolcontext) of [Tutorial: Get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-the-schoolcontext) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

> SARTUP.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using task.Models;

namespace task
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

 
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=About}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```